# подскажите пожалуйста в чем моя ошибка

Tags: postgresql

```
    DECLARE
    curs1 cursor FOR SELECT * FROM public."Clients" order by "Id";
    
FOR cl IN curs1 LOOP
    IF cl.IsVerificated THEN 
        if cl.MadeBasicInformStep = 9 then
            UPDATE public."Clients" SET IsVerificatedAsBorrower = true, InterviewSuccessful = true WHERE CURRENT OF curs1;
        end if;
        if cl.MadeDepositAccountStep >= 4 then
            UPDATE public."Clients" SET IsVerificatedAsInvestor = true WHERE CURRENT OF curs1;
        end if;
    END IF;
END LOOP;
```

подскажите пожалуйста в чем здесь ошибка

ERROR: ОШИБКА:  ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "FOR")
LINE 4: FOR cl IN curs1 LOOP
^

SQL-состояние: 42601
Символ: 78

Comment: Ну если это ВЕСЬ код - то ничего удивительного. Показанный код должен либо входить в состав compound statement (скажем, процедура), либо быть обёрнут в DO statement (выполняться как анонимный блок).

Comment: Спасибо помогло

Comment: А вообще постарайтесь в начале забыть про существование процедурного языка pl/sql и более углубленно изучать сам SQL. Ваша задача решается двумя простыми запросами `UPDATE public."Clients" SET IsVerificatedAsInvestor = true WHERE IsVerificated = true and cl.MadeDepositAccountStep >= 4;
UPDATE public."Clients" SET IsVerificatedAsBorrower = true, InterviewSuccessful = true WHERE IsVerificated = true and cl.MadeBasicInformStep = 9;`
И вполне может быть что они даже при двойном сканировании таблицы отработают быстрее, чем этот цикл. Хотя при желании можно и одним запросом обойтись,